# How do I append the values in a list to a dynamodb table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list containing dictionaries similar to the below example. I want to try and append each dictionary as a sperate item into an AWS Dynamodb table. Not sure how to make it happen. Example List with Dictionaries

```
[
{"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 1", "seq": 3, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 2", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 2", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 3", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 4", "seq": 1, "data": "datapoint"},
{"tbl_nm": "Table 4", "seq": 2, "data": "datapoint"}
```

]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('test_table')
    for i in dict:
        table.put_item(Item=i)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```